# Extract common columns(audit fields) [Java][JPA]

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Can we extract common columns like created by, created date, updated by, updated date as a separate POJO and extend this POJO in our JPA entities.

I tried it but the columns from extended POJO are not getting registered. Would like to understand why it happened and what can be a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this, is by created a common super class annotated with `MappedSuperclass`:

```
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.EntityListeners;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(TraceAbleListener.class)
public class TraceAble {
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdOn;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date updatedOn;
    private String createdBy;
    private String updatedBy;
    //getters setters, or use lombok @Date 
}
```

Then you just need to create an entity listener with appropriate JPA event handlers to create, update dates, users etc(`PrePersist, PreUpdate`...) or you can add those methods directly to your common super class.